# Create table with function values from other table?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am newbie here so maybe my question might seem pretty basic. My problem is this: I have four 4x6 tables with known values of which the user should use, within a function f, only one from  each table each time so that a new table with values for f is created. However, there is something wrong in my code which i cannot understand. Any suggestions?

Consider $d=1$ and $ksi=1000$ for my function

```
TEg0 = {{4.493410, 7.725252, 10.904120  14.066190, 17.220750, 
   20.371300},
  {5.763460, 9.095012, 12.322940, 15.5146000, 18.689040, 21.853870},
  {6.987932, 10.417120, 13.698020, 16.923620, 20.121810, 23.304250},
  {8.182562, 11.704910, 15.039660, 18.301260, 21.525420, 24.727570}}

TEg1g0 = {{0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000},
  {0.285714, 0.285714, 0.285714, 0.285729, 0.285716, 0.285729},
  {0.266667, 0.266667, 0.266667, 0.266667, 0.268331, 0.266667},
  {0.259752, 0.259752, 0.259785, 0.259741, 0.259751, 0.259764}}

TEg2g0 = {{0.318057, 0.405000, 0.540398, 0.720727, 0.945740, 1.216530}
   {0.234662, 0.330848, 0.467022, 0.639935, 0.848433, 1.098372},
  {0.109708, 0.0069634, -0.015400, -0.051312, -0.272904, -0.258691},
  {0.100111, 0.057204, 0.001593, -0.060967, -0.139916, -0.226860}}

TEg3g0 = {{0.000039, 0.000049, 0.000052, .000079, 0.000117, 0.000117},
  {0.000033, 0.000041, 0.000065, 0.000090, 0.000119, 0.000132},
  {0.000005, 0.000001, 0.000007, -0.000007, -0.000010, -0.000025},
  {0.000006, 0.000008, 0.000001, -0.000008, -0.000006, -0.000031}}

f[n_, s_, d_, ksi_] = 
 3*10^8*TEg0[[n, s]]/(Pi*d*ksi)*(1 + TEg1g0[[n, s]]*(1/ksi^2)^2 + 
    TEg2g0[[n, s]]*(1/ksi^2)^3 + TEg3g0[[n, s]]*(1/ksi^2)^4)

For[n = 1; s = 1, i < 5, i++, s++, s < 7, f[n_, s_, 1, 1000; Print[f]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain I've understood your question. However, if you intend to use the data (which I've cleaned up for you)

```
TEg0 = {{4.493410, 7.725252, 10.904120, 14.066190, 17.220750, 20.371300}, {5.763460, 9.095012, 12.322940, 15.5146000, 18.689040, 21.853870}, {6.987932, 10.417120, 13.698020, 16.923620, 20.121810, 23.304250}, {8.182562, 11.704910, 15.039660, 18.301260, 21.525420, 24.727570}};
TEg1g0 = {{0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000, 0.400000},{0.285714, 0.285714, 0.285714, 0.285729, 0.285716, 0.285729}, {0.266667, 0.266667, 0.266667, 0.266667, 0.268331, 0.266667}, {0.259752, 0.259752, 0.259785, 0.259741, 0.259751, 0.259764}};
TEg2g0 = {{0.318057, 0.405000, 0.540398, 0.720727, 0.945740, 1.216530}, {0.234662, 0.330848, 0.467022, 0.639935, 0.848433, 1.098372}, {0.109708, 0.0069634, -0.015400, -0.051312, -0.272904, -0.258691}, {0.100111, 0.057204, 0.001593, -0.060967, -0.139916, -0.226860}};
TEg3g0 = {{0.000039, 0.000049, 0.000052, .000079, 0.000117, 0.000117}, {0.000033, 0.000041, 0.000065, 0.000090, 0.000119, 0.000132}, {0.000005, 0.000001,     0.000007, -0.000007, -0.000010, -0.000025}, {0.000006, 0.000008, 0.000001, -0.000008, -0.000006, -0.000031}};
```

And you construct the following [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) to evaluate the various permutations

```
f[n_, s_, d_, ksi_] := 3*10^8*TEg0[[n, s]]/(\[Pi] d ksi) (1 + TEg1g0[[n, s]] (1/ksi^2)^2 + TEg2g0[[n, s]] (1/ksi^2)^3 + TEg3g0[[n, s]] (1/ksi^2)^4)
```

The you can use the [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) command as follows

```
Table[f[n, s, 1, 1000], {n, 1, 4}, {s, 1, 6}]
```

to get

```
{{429089., 737707., 1.04127*10^6, 1.34322*10^6, 1.64446*10^6, 1.94532*10^6}, 
{550370., 868510., 1.17675*10^6, 1.48154*10^6, 1.78467*10^6, 2.08689*10^6}, 
{667298., 994762., 1.30806*10^6, 1.61609*10^6, 1.92149*10^6, 2.22539*10^6}, 
{781377., 1.11774*10^6, 1.43618*10^6, 1.74764*10^6, 2.05553*10^6, 2.36131*10^6}}
```

Comment: That's correct! Thank you so much for your help!